# How to call one class into another classes main java

Tags: java, class, methods

I have a program with three classes, AdventureTest, CustomerContact, and Activities. I want to call information from the class Customer Contact into the main of the class AdventureTest. How do I do that? Am I able to call a whole class to run or do I have to call individual methods from the class CustomerContact.

Here is an example of two methods in the class CustomerContact

```
    public void setFirstName() {
    this.FirstName = FirstName
    }

    public string getFirstName(String firstname) {
    return FirstName;
    }
```

I have tried calling one of those methods by using CustomerContact.getFirstName; but it does not work. (I get the error "cannot find symbol") I think it would be simpler to call the whole class but I do not know how to do that. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: No, never put user interface code within a getter.

Comment: Please use the java convention for naming stuff. Capital case start for classes and all variables start with a lower case. This makes reading the code difficult...

Comment: What do you think the text within the braces is for?

Comment: @Timothy Truckle I have a list of different user input I'm supposed to take, like first name, last name, address, and phone number. The text within in the braces is for after calling the method and having the user enter input (Like their name) it saves the information there? At least that's how my teacher explained it.

Comment: either she explained it wrong or you did not understand it. See here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html

Answer (score 0):

In java you can only call static methods "directly". Otherwise you have to construct an instance of the object:

```
CustomerContact contact = new CustomerContact(...);
String firstName = contact.getFirstName("someName");
```

I'd like to also point out that the code you have written currently is full of mistakes and won't compile.